# Open terminated Flutter app using background notification (Android)

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, webrtc

I'm building Flutter android app for webrtc calls. When a call is coming I use Firebase Cloud Messages (background data messages) to notify my app. Using callkeep flutter plugin I can show incoming call screen. Everything works grate but I don't know how to open flutter app when it is terminated (not in background). I receive background notification and can run some code (e.g. show local notification, show incoming call screen) but I don't know how to open my app. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [connectycube_flutter_call_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/connectycube_flutter_call_kit) package after which you can then navigate to the desired screen

```
     ConnectycubeFlutterCallKit.instance.init(
       onCallAccepted: (String sessionId, int callType, int callerId,
           String callerName, Set opponentsIds
            , Map callOpponentsop
           ) async {
         // Navigator.pushNAmed()
         return null;
       },
       onCallRejected: (String sessionId, int callType, int callerId,
           String callerName, Set opponentsIds
            , Map callOpponents
           ) {
         return null;
       },
     );
```